# React Native Local/Remote Push Notification: How to get Click/Touch-Event with Payload?

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, react-native-push-notification

I develop a cross-platform hybrid app with **react native**.

I integrated **remote push notification** over Amazon SNS.

I tried many plugins but mostly **zo0r/react-native-push-notification**

The notification arrives on the android phone and a "onNotification"-callback is executed **instantly**. (on ios phone I have not tried it yet)

That is ok, but not what I need.

Whatever the state of the app is (in foreground, in background or closed) I want to get the **click/touch-event when the user touches on the notification**.

And I **need the payload** of the notification to open the suitable webview in the app where the user should be guided to.

I tried to handle the remote notification und pushed a new local notification but I neither got the event I am looking for.